# CC/BCC and comments section is missing in the SSRS subscription page

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssrs, ssrs-2012

We're using SSRS 2012.

We tried to limit the permission level of users, and assigned them "Manage Individual subscriptions" role, instead of "Content Manager" or "Subscription Manager", however, now when a user tries to create an email subscription for a report, the CC/BCC and Comments sections are missing.

See picture below.
[image: Manage Individual subscriptions]

With a higher role level, the subscription pages looks like:
[image: Manage ALL subscription role]

We can live without CC/Bcc, but the comments section is important to the users.
Can we some how enable this comment section and keep the role level low (Manage Individual subscriptions only)?